# how long does a query take to run?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I want to time a query. How do I do that? I want to change the order of the WHERE operators to see what will produce the best results; is this the best way to do it? I'm using sql server and .net 4.

Thanks.

Comment: I would echo what other people have said about using the profiler hower I think you are barking up the wrong tree with the order of items in the WHERE clause, it has no impact on the query http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/02/22/60527.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql Server Profiler will give you the best measurement of query speed.  It comes with the SQL Management Studio.

Comment: +1.  This sounds like a better and more reusable option than timing and logging your queries, unless you plan to leave the profiling in our final build and actually write it to your logs :)

Comment: I have a query that takes 11ms to execute. I'm running on my laptop with not much dummy data and of course no other user. Just on top of your hear, is it possible to say that this is a slow/fast query. I don't need 100% accurate answer, just a guess.

Comment: I would say that is pretty quick.  It really all depends on how complex the data is to retrieve (joins, subqueries, etc..).  Also your query execution speed will increase when you move the database to a dedicated machine

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing, you might be able to simply use a `Stopwatch` class to do your timing:

```
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
// Execute your query here
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time for query: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

Comment: I have a query that takes 11ms to execute. I'm running on my laptop with not much dummy data and of course no other user. Just on top of your hear, is it possible to say that this is a slow/fast query. I don't need 100% accurate answer, just a guess.

Comment: @frenchie: How many times can you snap your fingers in 11ms? ;)  If you're actually concerned with perf, you'll have to bite the bullet and populate it with data, and have a concurrent number of users that simulate (x2, or possibly more) your expected mean/peak usage.  Saying an app is "good enough to ship" when you've only tested it with a tiny amount of data/number of users is a sure-fire recipe for disaster once you actually have to scale (at all).  You won't know where any of the bottlenecks are.

Comment: But if a query were to take 2 minutes on my laptop, that'd be a sure sign of a problem. What about a query that takes half a second, still a sure sign? I guess I'm wondering at what threshold we can definetely say that there's a problem, given that it's running on a laptop with not much data (about 6000 rows in the main table it's pulling from).

Comment: @frenchie: Yep, it would be a sure sign.  So, you'll need to define your expected common user scenarios and expected load, then you actually test them.  Many of the apps that I've worked on were a first version, and already were decently quick, so I simply did my perf testing as a benchmark for further development.

Comment: @frenchie: If this is a tiny app with a tiny userbase, it probably doesn't matter how well it runs.  You can just let em know to report to you if stuff is too slow, and see if you can instrument your code so you can measure it yourself while it is running.  If you have larger ambitions, you should make the investment/take the time to test it more thoroughly.  By test, I mean just gather the data, and see if you have a problem, and keep that data around for future versions.  And of course look at it ;)

Comment: How much data in a table do I need to say that I'm "testing" the query. I understand that a real test is when we're testing the app with multiple concurrent users but at the moment, I'm developing it. I created a dummy data generator so I can generate as much data as I'd need. There are 19 tables with an average of 7-8 columns, though about 10 of these hold the bulk of the data. Most queries result in joins between 3-4 tables. How many rows do you recommend I fill?

Comment: @frenchie: I recommend you determine what the data will look like in real life, and double it.  I have no idea what that will mean for your app, and someone would have to consult on your app for a while to be able to give you reasonable data.  You may have to fill tens or hundreds of thousands of rows in each, or maybe only hundreds.